# Quizás or quizá, which one is preferred?

Tags: gramática, selección-de-palabras, adverbios

The [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UxkB7hL) redirects the definition of *quizás* to *quizá*, but I wonder if there's any implicit, secret rule that I am not aware of as to whether *quizás* is preferred over *quizá*.

I've seen both forms used almost indistinguishably even in the same text.

What's your take on this? Would you use both words in the same text? Do you have a rule to choose one or the other, depending on the word following it, for example?

Comment: +1 as I did not even realize that there were two different words >.<

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are exactly the same, as the *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* says [here](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/?key=quiz%C3%A1&origen=REDPD):

> **quizá**. Adverbio que expresa duda o probabilidad: *«Neruda es un gran
>   poeta. Quizá el más grande de todos los poetas»* (Skármeta *Cartero*
>   [Chile 1986]). **Por analogía con otros adverbios acabados en *-s***, se
>   creó la forma ***quizás***, igualmente válida: *«Quizás Casiana tenga razón»*
>   (Parrado *1905* [Cuba 1984]).

So the original one was *"**quizá**"* but *"**quizás**"* was created because other adverbs also ended in "s".

I use both forms (I'm not sure if I tend to use one more than the other). But the [Ngram Viewer of Google](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quiz%C3%A1s,quiz%C3%A1,Quiz%C3%A1s,Quiz%C3%A1&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=10&smoothing=3) says that *"**quizá**"* is more used though in the past the difference was much bigger than nowadays.

[image]

Comment: Javi, thanks for the graph, very interesting stuff. So the form `quizás` exists even before the 1800's, huh? Google es definitivamente una maravilla :)

Comment: La verdad es que `quizá` me suena medio raro, siempre uso `quizás` :) [Quizás, quizás, quizás](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiz%C3%A1s,_Quiz%C3%A1s,_Quiz%C3%A1s)

Comment: +1 for the reference to the Ngram Viewer.  Amazing.

Answer (score 9):

Both, but the original word (if any word can be original) is *"quizá"*.

It comes from Latin *"qui sapit"* meaning "Who knows?".

The first documentation of the word appears on the famous work *Cantares del Mio Cid*:

> Allá dentro en Marruecos,
> ó las mezquitas son,
> que abrán de mí salto
>
> **quiçab** alguna noch,
> ellos lo temen,
> ca non lo pienso yo;

(At least that's what it says on my Latin etymology dictionary)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's any difference. Or at least I'm not aware of it. As you say, they are used indistinctively. The [DPD also says they are equivalent](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/?key=quiz%C3%A1&origen=REDPD).

I tend to use *quizá*, buy it's just a matter of preference.

Maybe, if the following word starts with an "s" I would avoid using *quizás*, so it's easier to pronounce, but there's no explicit or implicit rule about it.

Answer (score 2):

Use *quizás* when the next word starts with a vowel. Use *quizá* when the next word starts with a consonant as in the examples below:

- quizá podemos - maybe we can
- quizás ella puede - maybe she can

This is like the English "a" and "an." You don't say "a animal," you say "an animal" so that you don't have an 'A sound' followed by another 'A sound.'

Comment: That is interesting.  Is it a rule you came up with, based on observation, or did you learn this somewhere?  It would be interesting to know the origin of the rule.  Also, if this is a regional rule, it would be helpful to know what your region is.  Thanks, Guest, and welcome to the site!

Comment: @aparente001 I agree with Guest that, traditionally, it was taught that way. In "Gramática histórica de la lengua castellana", the author says: *Nosotros nos atreveríamos, si para ello tuviéramos autoridad 
suficiente, a recomendar la forma "quizá" cuando precede a conso- 
nante y "quizás" antes de vocal*.

Comment: @walen "quizá alguien" and the like are really cacophonic. The "s" is best to create liaison between the two vowels.

Comment: @Gustavson - Shall we wait a day or two, and if Guest doesn't edit the answer, you could add the material from your comment?

Comment: @walen En este artículo (entre otros que hay en Internet): http://www.estandarte.com/noticias/idioma-espanol/quizs-o-quiz_1170.html puede leerse: En general podemos decir que, movidos por motivos fonéticos, tendemos a decir *quizá* cuando la palabra que se escribe a continuación empieza con consonante, y *quizás* si la palabra que sigue empieza por vocal. Así, decimos: Quizá llame a Laura esta tarde, y Quizás encuentres lo que buscas en otro lugar.

Comment: Otra opinión en el mismo sentido: 1. ¿Quizá, o quizás?
Se utiliza “quizá” cuando la siguiente palabra comienza con consonante.
- Ejemplo: Quizá se perdió.
Y se utiliza quizás cuando la siguiente palabra comienza con vocal.
- Ejemplo: Quizás antes de las tres. (https://www.uexternado.edu.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/4.-Algunas-dudas-comunes.pdf)

Comment: Otra más: ¿Se escribe quizá o quizás?
Respuesta: Depende, si la siguiente palabra comienza con una vocal se usa quizás, por ejemplo: "Quizás aquí no pueda fumar"; si la siguiente palabra comienza con una consonante se usa quizá, por ejemplo: "Quizá sea lo mejor". (http://csh.izt.uam.mx/ortografia/dudasfrecuentes/dudas.html) No sigo para no cansar: sólo quiero demostrar que no es un invento mío, sino la opinión de muchos hablantes de distintos lugares.